# Identify a manufacturer and year of manufacture of an old folding wooden camera

Tags: film, camera, vintage, old-cameras

I would like to know what is the factory of this old folding wooden camera, and what is the probable year of production?

From a photographer who uses this camera, I have learned that it is probably the camera from some American company, but he wasn't pretty sure. The lens is *Schneider-Kreuznach Xenar f4.5 180 mm (serial number 7363224) Compur*.

I've tried to find exactly the same camera through image search services, but without success.

[image: the old folding wooden camera]
[image: the front of the old folidng wooden camera]

I'm expecting any hints or clue which a company could build this camera.

Answer (score 1):

Having had a poke about the net, it looks possible it's made by Lamperti & Garbagnati Milano, highly unlikely that the lens is original.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, I've traversed catwiki website and found something like this: https://www.catawiki.com/en/l/34874647-beautiful-unmarked-travel-wooden-camera-9x12cm-with-lens-goerz-lynkeioskop-serie-e-n-2-c-1920

Rear fittings look pretty the same. I think it can be no name or Ernemann Globus.